# Copy Files from folder to folder on base of md5sum

Tags: scripts

I have a problem regarding to copying files,

**Problem :** I have a list of md5sum, and a folder having 1000+ files, How can I move 
files from folder to another folder with the help of md5sum list.

I can take md5sum against all files, currently present in folder, now what script 
to to get read scripts from a list then compare the md5sum with list's 
md5sum. If they are matched than the script move to another location.

> Reading md5sum of files (little code) 
>       for i in `ls` ; do md5=`md5sum "${i}"` ;
>
> *I don't know what condition will come here! to read list and compare with lists md5sum* 
>   ; mv "${i}" $m ; done

If it's possible then please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: I have md5sum, mean I am able to get md5sum (filename) if file md5sum is matched with the list then something in script to move the folder to another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0|xargs -0r md5sum|\
sed 's!^\([0-9a-f]\{32\}\)[     ]\+\(.*\)$!mkdir \1; mv -it \1 "\2"!'
```